# Create a trendline via flot?

Tags: jquery, flot

I have gone through the flot examples and have searched via Google for how to create a trendline in flot. There doesn't seem to be an option available for adding a trendline. Any hints or information on this would be great.

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_line_(technical_analysis)?  Isn't it just another line series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trend line plugin for flot, but it may need some additional work: [flot issue 270](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=270) (download link after the first post)